# Reformulate an equation to me faster in java

Tags: java, function, math, encryption, modulus

I'm working on encryption, and for the private key exponent `d`, you need to multiply d by e and take the mod of another number, and have the remainder be 1. the function i have already is this:

```
private void genD() {
        d = e / 2;
        // solve for d given d*e = 1 (mod eN)
        while ((d * e) % eN != 1) {
            d++;
        }
}
```

what i have now is obviously a brute way of doing things, going through every single number until one works. I know the equation does its job, plugging in the numbers using the working example found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#A_worked_example), but it is VERY VERY VERY slow with using for the numbers i'm generating. Logically I feel there is a way to get this done MUCH faster, but I'm unable to think of how?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are fast multiplicative inverse algorithms which aren't terribly difficult, but there's also one built into Java:

```
 BigInteger.valueOf(e).modInverse(BigInteger.valueOf(eN)).intValue();
```

The most popular algorithm to compute the multiplicative inverse mod another number is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers .

Comment: wow this was WAY better than expected! Thank you so very much, and thank you for that link as well to fill my free time :) consider this the answer :) i'll accept when i can